# Display text/attribute in product detail page - Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2.3.2

I want to display text/attribute in product detail page - magento 2.3.2.

In Magento 1.9.4 we can code in view.phtml file located under public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product to achieve this result.

But In Magento 2.3.2 there is no view.phtml file. anyone please let me know where & how to code to display text/attribute in product detail page - magento 2.3.2

Comment: sku already display in product detail page.

Comment: consider it as to display text/ any attribute

Comment: $_product->getCustomAttributte()

Comment: can you please give more in detail.... location of file, name of file and exact code if my attribute name to display is 'exam'

Comment: in which location ??

Comment: In Magento 2.3.2 I want to display attrubute 'exam' in product detail page. How can I achieve this? which file I need to code? where that file located?

Answer (score 0):

Override:
/app/design/frontend/Themename/campponyname/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view

```
<?php 
try { $product_description = $_item->getData('attributeName');
if ( $product_description && strlen($product_description) ) {
?><div class="desciption">
<p><?= $product_description ?></p></div><?php
}
} catch(Exception $e) {}
?>
```

For catalog page:
path:app/design/frontend/themename/companyname/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
 <?php 
$attr = $_product->getData('attributename');
if ( $attr && strlen($attr) ) {
?><div class="whatever"><p><?= $attr ?></p></div><?php
}
?>
```

Comment: pl.let me know exact file name to code...to display in product detail page.
(like you mentioned list.phtml for catalogue page)

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view
check this path
this path contain all product page files you have to check all file that are placed in this folder and change you code accordingly

Comment: if i want to display attribute just above product image which file out of product page files I have to code & what code to mention.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

Comment: it is not working..for me